# Store dynamically created checkbox value in another table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, checkbox

I have the following code to dynamically generate check-boxes from one table:

```
{!! Form::open(['url' =>URL::to('admin/user/'.$profileUser->id) , 'method'=>'PUT', 'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data' ]) !!}
                    @foreach ($userRoles as $key => $userRole)
                    <tr>
                        <td width="10%">{{ Form::label($userRole->name) }}</td>
                        <td>{{ Form::checkbox( 'rolename[]', $userRole->id) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    <tr>{{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'btn', 'name' => 'roleSubmit')) }}</tr>
            </tbody>
            {{ Form::close() }}
```

In the controller I have:

```
    if (isset($_POST['roleSubmit'])){
        DB::table('role_users')->where('user_id', $request->get('id', $id))->delete();


        $userRole = json_encode($request->input('rolename'));
        DB::table('role_users')->insert(
            array(
                'user_id' => $id,
                'role_id' => $userRole
            )
        );
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

I need to dynamically generate multiple checkboxes from 'roles' table[image]

and display like this:
[image]

Then I need to store the checkbox values in 'role_users' like this:[image]

Instead, for the above snippet of code, I am getting this: [image]

Any guideline where I am messing it?

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
if (isset($_POST['roleSubmit'])){
    DB::table('role_users')->where('user_id', $request->get('id', $id))->delete();


    $userRole = $request->input('rolename');
    foreach($userRole as $role){
        DB::table('role_users')->insert(
           array(
             'user_id' => $id,
             'role_id' => $role
           )
        );
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Per 2nd request

Controller

```
$RoleByUser = DB::table('role_users')
                  ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                  ->get()
                  ->pluck('role_id')
                  ->ToArray();
```

Blade

```
{{ Form::checkbox( 'rolename[]', $userRole->id, (in_array($userRole->id, $RoleByUser)) ? true : false) }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) It makes sense and that solved it.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me figure out how to show the chekcboxes that are being generated from 'roles', marked or unmarked based on values from 'roles' table.

Comment: Added the changes.